# Which API version for the Android tablet?

Tags: android, api, tablet

I'm making a program for an Android tablet, and have been using the SDK with API level 12 (Android 3.1), without much thought or knowledge of it, just because it's the newest one. But, which one would you recommend I use? Which ones are for tablets (as opposed to phones)? And, do I have to reinstall all of the SDK if I want to use a different API (as http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/install-android-sdk-eclipse-and-emulator-avds/ seems to suggest) or can I just create a new virtual device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use API level 11 that is the one that Google targeted for tablets. Previous version will work with tablets too, but the API 11 itself includes features that are tablet-specific.

And no, you don't have to reinstall the SDK. Just install that additional API level, and create a new virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go for 3.0 since there are tablets that run that.

You only need to download the platform for 3.0 if you don't already have it. No need to reinstall the complete sdk. Just download the appropriate files.

Answer (score 0):

minimum API level is GALAXY_Tab Addon - API Level 8 for the tablet and Android HoneyComb-API Level Honeycomb for the Honeycomb devlopment.